# Assigning parsers to auto variables

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit-qi

Are spirit parsers not meant to be used with `auto`?

A simple parser works fine when passed to `qi::parse()` inline, but crashes with segfault if passed via an `auto` variable:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    string line = "[z]";

    auto bracketed_z = '[' >> +qi::char_('z') >> ']';

    auto p = line.cbegin();
    printf("%d", qi::parse(p, line.cend(), '[' >> +qi::char_('z') >> ']'));  // Works

    p = line.cbegin();
    printf("%d", qi::parse(p, line.cend(), bracketed_z));                    // Crashes
}
```

Reproes with g++-4.8 and VC13.

Update: an error was fixed in the original code (`p` was not re-initialized before the second call to `parse()`).

Comment: How can any c++ parser deal with `auto`? Parsers are meant to read particular types determined at runtime, `auto` types are resolved at compile time. So IMHO unless the `auto` results in a `boost::variant` or `boost::any` it's not possible.

Comment: Note that the first iterator is passed by reference (IIRC). That is, `p` has been changed after the first call to `qi::parse`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: in this simple example it all should be compile-time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spirit Parsers are not designed to be used with `auto` in Spirit V2.

This is because the underlying Proto expression templates hold references to the temporaries.

You can use

- `qi::copy()`  (existing in the trunk after boost_1_55_0, not in any released version at this time)
- `boost::proto::deep_copy`
- or BOOST_SPIRIT_AUTO (first coined [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/zero-to-60-mph-in-2-seconds/))

I've written about these things more often on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+deep_copy, specifically, this:

- [boost spirit V2 qi bug associated with optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763665/boost-spirit-v2-qi-bug-associated-with-optimization-level/20766909#20766909)

Boost Spirit X3 will not have this limitation.

Comment: The error recently is too often encountered. Thus there is the NEED to have contemporary version of Boost.Spirit Qi library, which must be C++11/C++1y fully enabled (I think it should contain at least support for move-semantic).

Comment: @Dukales this appears to be an opinion in need of citation :) If you mean you're eager to see Spirit X3, +1

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Spirit uses expression templates and does not work with `auto`. A workaround is to use `boost::proto::deep_copy`:

```
auto bracketed_z = proto::deep_copy('[' >> +qi::char_('z') >> ']');
```