# boost spirit qi parser failed in release and pass in debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

```
 #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iostream>
using namespace boost::spirit;
int main()
{
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
auto specialtxt = *(qi::char_('-', '.', '_'));
auto txt = no_skip[*(qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_.\\:$\'-"))];
auto anytxt = *(qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_.\\:${}[]+/()-"));
qi::rule <std::string::iterator, void(),ascii::space_type> rule2 = txt     ('=') >> ('[') >> (']');
auto begin = s.begin();
auto end = s.end();
if (qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, rule2, ascii::space))
{
    std::cout << "MATCH" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "NO MATCH" << std::endl;
}

}
```

this code works fine in debug mode
parser fails in release mode
rule is to just parse text=[]; any thing else than this should fail it works fine in debug mode but not in release mode it shows result no match for any string.

if i enter string like

```
abc=[];
```

this passes in debug as expected but fails in release

Comment: I will review the actual parser soon. Be back later

Comment: What is `txt('=')` supposed to do? It's not a  valid Qi expression in the first place...

Comment: actually it is txt>>('=') and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use auto with Spirit v2:

- [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)

You have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

### DEMO

I tried to make (more) sense of the rest of the code. There were various instances that would never work:

1. `txt('=')` is an invalid Qi expression. I assumed you wanted `txt >> ('=')` instead
2. `qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_.\\:$\\-{}[]+/()")` doesn't do what you think because `$-{` is actually the character "range" `\x24-\x7b`... Escape the `-` (or put it at the very end/start of the set like in the other char_ call).
3. `qi::char_('-','.','_')` can't work. Did you mean `qi::char_("-._")`?
4. `specialtxt` and `anytxt` were unused...
5. prefer `const_iterator`
6. prefer namespace aliases above `using namespace` to prevent hard-to-detect errors

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/715985055d88a0d0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    std::string const s = "abc=[];";

    auto specialtxt = qi::copy(*(qi::char_("-._")));
    auto anytxt     = qi::copy(*(qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_.\\:$\\-{}[]+/()")));
    (void) specialtxt;
    (void) anytxt;

    auto txt        = qi::copy(qi::no_skip[*(qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_.\\:$\'-"))]);

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, qi::space_type> rule2 = txt >> '=' >> '[' >> ']';

    auto begin = s.begin();
    auto end   = s.end();

    if (qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, rule2, qi::space)) {
        std::cout << "MATCH" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "NO MATCH" << std::endl;
    }

    if (begin != end) {
        std::cout << "Trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(begin, end) << "'\n";
    }

}
```

Printing

```
MATCH
Trailing unparsed: ';'
```

Comment: Added a fixed demo with (lots of) notes: recorded live session  https://www.livecoding.tv/video/fixingreviewing-a-random-spirit-grammar/

Comment: thanks man this is very useful
in my application LHS value can be any thing like
ab$c=[]; or
xy.123z=[];
xy-3.0_z=[];
so it is kind of generic rule with it i can parse any kind of left side text