# decode http header value fully with boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Once again, I find myself reaching for boost spirit. Once again I find myself defeated by it.

A HTTP header *value* takes the general form:

```
text/html; q=1.0, text/*; q=0.8, image/gif; q=0.6, image/jpeg; q=0.6, image/*; q=0.5, */*; q=0.1
```

i.e. `value *OWS [; *OWS name *OWS [= *OWS possibly_quoted_value] *OWS [...]] *OWS  [ , <another value> ...]`

so in my mind, this header decodes to:

```
value[0]: 
  text/html
  params:
    name : q
    value : 1.0
value[1]:
  text/*
  params:
    name : q
    value : 0.8
...
```

and so on.

I am certain that to anyone who knows how, the boost::spirit::qi syntax for this is trivial.

I humbly ask for your assistance.

for example, here's the outline of the code which decodes the `Content-Type` header, which is limited to one value of the form `type/subtype`, with any number of parameters of the form `<sp> ; <sp> token=token|quoted_string`

```
template<class Iter>
void parse(ContentType& ct, Iter first, Iter last)
{
    ct.mutable_type()->append(to_lower(consume_token(first, last)));
    consume_lit(first, last, '/');
    ct.mutable_subtype()->append(to_lower(consume_token(first, last)));
    while (first != last) {
        skipwhite(first, last);
        if (consume_char_if(first, last, ';'))
        {
            auto p = ct.add_parameters();
            skipwhite(first, last);
            p->set_name(to_lower(consume_token(first, last)));
            skipwhite(first, last);
            if (consume_char_if(first, last, '='))
            {
                skipwhite(first, last);
                p->set_value(consume_token_or_quoted(first, last));
            }
            else {
                // no value on this parameter
            }
        }
        else if (consume_char_if(first, last, ','))
        {
            // normally we should get the next value-token here but in the case of Content-Type
            // we must barf
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid use of ; in Content-Type");
        }
    }
}

ContentType& populate(ContentType& ct, const std::string& header_value)
{
    parse(ct, header_value.begin(), header_value.end());
    return ct;
}
```

Comment: Can you link the RFC? I don't recognize that spec.

Comment: @sehe many thanks. I probably didn't write it very well...
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2

Comment: @sehe to my mind the interesting (and actually quite complex) thing about HTTP headers is that '/' is a separator, which separates values within a value. So actually value[0] should itself be a vector of values: "text", "html" with added properties ("q"="1.0") and so on.

Comment: @RichardHodges: There is a very simple http header parser given in the example code associated to `boost::asio`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/request_parser.cpp However, an advantage of that, and a drawback of spirit, is that that kind of parser can be "interrupted" and resumed if it runs out of text to parse. Spirit does not support "tristate" parsing, i.e. "good, fail, not finished". In spirit AFAIK if you run out of text to parse, the state of the parser will be lost when it returns. So, I think you don't actually want spirit for this.

Comment: I guess maybe you aren't using it for a server or something, or you are using it in some kind of situation where you will always have the full header, or can afford to reparse?

Comment: @ChrisBeck I've written an http server which stores the header in a protobuf message, so I have the full header value. Now I want to reparse the value to turn each header type's value into it own stucture (many will be similar of course). This then makes using the header's contents easy as its a simple api call. .e.g `if (header.content_type().type() == "application" && header.content_type().subtype == "json")...`

Comment: @ChrisBeck the rationale for using protobuf to store http headers (and payloads) is that I can hand off protobuf services calls which have arrived via http onto a bus for further handling.

Comment: @sehe finally came up with an answer. I'd value your expert eye on it.

Comment: @RichardHodges consider it done. I think you could simplify to do without the variant. I'll show that for fun. Hold on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken the code as [posted by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37865999/85371) and given it a review.

1. there's no need to specify `void()`. In fact it's preferable to use `qi::unused_type` in such cases, which is what rules will default to if no attribute type is declared.
2. there no need for `char_` if you don't wish to expose the attribute. Use `lit` instead.
3. there is no need to wrap every char parser in a `rule`. That hurts performance. It's best to leave the proto expression tree un-evaluated as long so Qi can optimize parser expressions more, and the compiler can inline more.

   Also, Qi doesn't have move semantics on attributes, so avoiding redundant rules eliminates redundant copies of sub-attributes that get concatenated in the containing rules.

   > Sample alternative spelling (caution, see [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables))
   >
   > ```
   > auto CR   = qi::lit('\r');
   > auto LF   = qi::lit('\n');
   > auto CRLF = qi::lit("\r\n");
   > auto HT   = qi::lit('\t');
   > auto SP   = qi::lit(' ');
   > auto LWS  = qi::copy(-CRLF >> +(SP | HT)); // deepcopy
   >
   > UPALPHA = char_('A', 'Z');
   > LOALPHA = char_('a', 'z');
   > ALPHA   = UPALPHA | LOALPHA;
   > DIGIT   = char_('0', '9');
   > //CTL     = char_(0, 31) | char_(127);
   > TEXT    = char_("\t\x20-\x7e\x80-\xff");
   > ```
4. Since you didn't have to use `char_`, you also don't have kill the attribute using `qi::omit[]`.
5. When you are in a Qi domain expression template, raw string/char literals are implicitly wrapped in a `qi::lit` so, you can simply things like

   ```
   quoted_pair   = omit[char_('\\')] >> char_;
   quoted_string = omit[char_('"')] >> *(qdtext | quoted_pair) >> omit[char_('"')];
   ```

   to just

   ```
   quoted_pair   = '\\' >> char_;
   quoted_string = '"' >> *(qdtext | quoted_pair) >> '"';
   ```
6. instead of spelling out skipping spaces with `omit[*SP]` all the time, just declare the rule with a skipper. Now, you can simplify

   ```
   nvp               = token >> omit[*SP] >> omit['='] >> omit[*SP] >> value;
   any_parameter     = omit[*SP] >> omit[char_(';')] >> omit[*SP] >> (nvp | name_only);
   content_type_rule = type_subtype_rule >> *any_parameter;
   ```

   to just

   ```
   nvp               = token >> '=' >> value;
   any_parameter     = ';' >> (nvp | name_only);
   content_type_rule = type_subtype_rule >> qi::skip(spaces)[*any_parameter];
   ```

   > Note that any subrule invocations of rules that are declared without a skipper are *implicitly lexeme*: [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)
7. there were many redundant/unused headers
8. recent compilers + boost versions make BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT much simpler by using `decltype`

The results of simplifying are much less noisy:

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>

struct parameter {
    boost::optional<std::string> name;
    std::string value;
};

struct type_subtype {
    std::string type;
    std::string subtype;
};

struct content_type {
    type_subtype type;
    std::vector<parameter> params;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(type_subtype, type, subtype)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(content_type, type, params)

template<class Iterator>
struct token_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, content_type()>
{
    token_grammar() : token_grammar::base_type(content_type_rule)
    {
        using qi::ascii::char_;

        spaces        = char_(' ');
        token         = +~char_( "()<>@,;:\\\"/[]?={} \t");
        quoted_string = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
        value         = quoted_string | token;

        type_subtype_rule = token >> '/' >> token;
        name_only         = token;
        nvp               = token >> '=' >> value;
        any_parameter     = ';' >> (nvp | name_only);
        content_type_rule = type_subtype_rule >> qi::skip(spaces) [*any_parameter];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((nvp)(any_parameter)(content_type_rule)(quoted_string)(token)(value)(type_subtype_rule))
    }

  private:
    using Skipper = qi::space_type;
    Skipper spaces;

    qi::rule<Iterator, binary_parameter(), Skipper> nvp;
    qi::rule<Iterator, parameter(), Skipper>        any_parameter;
    qi::rule<Iterator, content_type()>              content_type_rule;

    // lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>               quoted_string, token, value;
    qi::rule<Iterator, type_subtype()>              type_subtype_rule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, unary_parameter()>           name_only;
};
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c294a7ce13db259)</kbd>** (with the same test cases)

### BONUS

I'd prefer a simpler AST in a case like this. By injecting some attribute values using `qi::attr` you can [avoid using boost::variant](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c294a7ce13db259) and/or [even avoid boost::optional](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f3b3d489012b0b3):

```
struct parameter {
    bool have_name;
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
};

struct type_subtype {
    std::string type;
    std::string subtype;
};

struct content_type {
    type_subtype type;
    std::vector<parameter> params;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(parameter, have_name, name, value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(type_subtype, type, subtype)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(content_type, type, params)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template<class Iterator>
struct token_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, content_type()>
{
    token_grammar() : token_grammar::base_type(content_type_rule)
    {
        using qi::ascii::char_;

        spaces        = char_(' ');
        token         = +~char_( "()<>@,;:\\\"/[]?={} \t");
        quoted_string = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
        value         = quoted_string | token;

        type_subtype_rule = token >> '/' >> token;
        name_only         = qi::attr(false) >> qi::attr("") >> token;
        nvp               = qi::attr(true)  >> token >> '=' >> value;
        any_parameter     = ';' >> (nvp | name_only);
        content_type_rule = type_subtype_rule >> qi::skip(spaces) [*any_parameter];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((nvp)(any_parameter)(content_type_rule)(quoted_string)(token)(value)(type_subtype_rule))
    }

  private:
    using Skipper = qi::space_type;
    Skipper spaces;

    qi::rule<Iterator, parameter(), Skipper> nvp, name_only, any_parameter;
    qi::rule<Iterator, content_type()>       content_type_rule;

    // lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>        quoted_string, token, value;
    qi::rule<Iterator, type_subtype()>       type_subtype_rule;
};
```

Comment: Many thanks. One question. The only place that spaces are disallowed is in the type/subtype rule. In this case, is it ok to add a skipper to the content_type rule? I take it that the presence of a skipper in an outer rule will not impose one on a non-skipping subrule?

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that - with a link to a background answer related to skippers :)

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit and put it in simpler terms for me. I find the interrelations between rules a little baffling :)

Comment: Here's a version [without using variants](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c294a7ce13db259) and one [without even using boost::oprional](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f3b3d489012b0b3) in the AST types.

Comment: The best clue I can give is "lexemes" don't skip anything. So, that's what I meant with he block-quote under item 6.

Comment: Ah I see it now. The skipper is on the any_parameter rule. Mea culpa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114886/discussion-between-sehe-and-richard-hodges).

Comment: Wow, the new fusion code is a little jarring... going to have to look at the docs to see how that actually works.

Comment: @sehe thank you for the update. I have a feeling that the http spec defines space as SP|HT but that's a minor issue. One last question. Obviously this is all well and good for one header type. Is it reasonable to put the basic rules into a base class if I want discrete grammars for each header type? Obviously I want to avoid redundant construction/reconstruction if headers are missing/present... Or should I ask another question about that?

Comment: When composing grammars, I don't think inheritance is a useful technique. Of course you can create separate grammars, and (re)use them inside other grammars. Even for literally /shared/ grammar rules, consider passing a reference to the grammar containing the stateless, shared rules to the other grammar's constructor. In Qi, rules constitute a compilation firewall anyways (think type erasure) so there's no gain in terms of performance for duplicating them locally.

Comment: @sehe i see. While you were writing that... I have another question (using inheritance, but that's besides the point) - it's about neat error handling. Hope you find it interesting :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879781/boost-spirit-improving-error-output

Answer (score 4):

OK, after an heroic 24 hours of struggle (well, not really - more like reading the manual over and over again...), I've found *a* way that works.

I am by no means competent with `boost::spirit`. If someone out there can improve on this answer, please do post it.

This spirit state machine takes the value of a header (with one, optionally parameterised, value) and turns it into a `content_type` structure.

My amateur reading of the HTTP standard indicates that some headers have the form (spaces here indicate any amount of white space, values may be quoted or not:

```
Header-Name: tokena/tokenb [; param1 = "value" [; param2 = value]...]
```

whereas others have the more general form:

```
Header-Name: token [; param1 = "value"[; param2 = value]...] [ , token ...]
```

This code covers the first case - i.e. the HTTP `Content-Type` header value. I will need to extend it to cater for the `Accept` header (which can advertise multiple values with parameters) - that will come later.

So here's the code. Please by all means show me how to improve it!!

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

using unary_parameter = std::string;

struct binary_parameter
{
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(binary_parameter,
                          (std::string, name)
                          (std::string, value))

using parameter = boost::variant<unary_parameter, binary_parameter>;

struct type_subtype
{
    std::string type;
    std::string subtype;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(type_subtype,
                          (std::string, type)
                          (std::string, subtype))

using content_type_pair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

struct content_type
{
    type_subtype type;
    std::vector<parameter> params;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(content_type,
                          (type_subtype, type)
                          (std::vector<parameter>, params))

template<class Iterator>
struct token_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, content_type()>
{

    token_grammar() : token_grammar::base_type(content_type_rule)
    {
        using ascii::char_;
        using qi::omit;
        using qi::eoi;

        CR = char_('\r');
        LF = char_('\n');
        CRLF = CR >> LF;
        SP = char_(' ');
        HT = char_('\t');
        LWS = -CRLF >> +(SP | HT);

        UPALPHA = char_('A', 'Z');
        LOALPHA = char_('a', 'z');
        ALPHA = UPALPHA | LOALPHA;
        DIGIT = char_('0', '9');
        CTL = char_(0, 31) | char_(127);
        QUOT = char_('"');
        TEXT = (char_ - CTL) | HT;

        separator = char_('(') | ')' | '<' | '>' | '@'
        | ',' | ';' | ':' | '\\' | '"'
        | '/' | '[' | ']' | '?' | '='
        | '{' | '}' | SP | HT;

        end_sequence = separator | space;
        token = +(char_ - separator);

        qdtext = char_ - char_('"') - '\\';
        quoted_pair = omit[char_('\\')] >> char_;
        quoted_string = omit[char_('"')] >> *(qdtext | quoted_pair) >> omit[char_('"')];
        value = quoted_string | token ;

        type_subtype_rule = token >> '/' >> token;
        name_only = token;
        nvp = token >> omit[*SP] >> omit['='] >> omit[*SP] >> value;
        any_parameter = omit[*SP] >> omit[char_(';')] >> omit[*SP] >> (nvp | name_only);
        content_type_rule = type_subtype_rule >> *any_parameter;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((qdtext)(quoted_pair)(quoted_string)(value)(token)(separator));
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, void()> CR, LF, CRLF, SP, HT, LWS, CTL, QUOT;
    qi::rule<Iterator, char()> UPALPHA, LOALPHA, ALPHA, DIGIT, TEXT, qdtext, quoted_pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, void()> separator, space, end_sequence;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> quoted_string, token, value;
    qi::rule<Iterator, type_subtype()> type_subtype_rule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, unary_parameter()> name_only;
    qi::rule<Iterator, binary_parameter()> nvp;
    qi::rule<Iterator, parameter()> any_parameter;
    qi::rule<Iterator, content_type()> content_type_rule;

};

TEST(spirit_test, test1)
{
    token_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> grammar{};

    std::string test = R"__test(application/json )__test";
    content_type ct;
    bool r = qi::parse(test.cbegin(), test.cend(), grammar, ct);
    EXPECT_EQ("application", ct.type.type);
    EXPECT_EQ("json", ct.type.subtype);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, ct.params.size());

    ct = {};
    test = R"__test(text/html ; charset = "ISO-8859-5")__test";
    qi::parse(test.cbegin(), test.cend(), grammar, ct);
    EXPECT_EQ("text", ct.type.type);
    EXPECT_EQ("html", ct.type.subtype);
    ASSERT_EQ(1, ct.params.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(typeid(binary_parameter), ct.params[0].type());
    auto& x = boost::get<binary_parameter>(ct.params[0]);
    EXPECT_EQ("charset", x.name);
    EXPECT_EQ("ISO-8859-5", x.value);

}
```