# Using too many alternative operator in boost::qi caused segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I generated a simple code using qi::spirit:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::spirit;
int main() {
    string str = "string";
    auto begin = str.begin();
    auto symbols = (qi::lit(";") | qi::lit("(") | qi::lit(")") | qi::lit("+") |
                    qi::lit("/") | qi::lit("-") | qi::lit("*"));
    qi::parse(begin, str.end(), *(qi::char_ - symbols));
}
```

And then this program was terminated by SEGV.Then,
my rewritten code with less alternative operators in rhs of symbols,

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::spirit;
int main()
{
    string str = "string";
    auto begin = str.begin();
    auto symbols = (qi::lit(";") | qi::lit("+") | qi::lit("/") | qi::lit("-") |
            qi::lit("*"));
    qi::parse(begin, str.end(), *(qi::char_ - symbols));
}
```

now works well. What's the difference between 2 cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a classic mistake: using `auto` to store Qi parser expressions: [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)

That leads to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

- Use a rule, or `qi::copy` (which is `proto::deep_copy` under the hooed).

  ```
  auto symbols = qi::copy(qi::lit(";") | qi::lit("(") | qi::lit(")") | qi::lit("+") |
       qi::lit("/") | qi::lit("-") | qi::lit("*"));
  ```
- Even better, use a character set to match all the characters at once,

  ```
  auto symbols = qi::copy(qi::omit(qi::char_(";()+/*-")));
  ```

  The `omit[]` counteracts the fact that `char_` exposes it's attribute (where `lit` doesn't). But since all you ever you it for is to SUBTRACT from another character-set:

  ```
  qi::char_ - symbols
  ```

  You could just as well just write

  ```
  qi::char_ - qi::char_(";()+/*-")
  ```

  Now. You might not know, but you can use `~charset` to negate it, so it would just become

  ```
  ~qi::char_(";()+/*-")
  ```

  > **NOTE** `-` can have special meaning in charsets, which is why I very subtly move it to the end. See [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html#spirit.qi.reference.char.char.char__def_)

### Live Demo

Extending a little and showing some subtler patterns:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0e93ff754a931de)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::spirit;
int main() {
    string const str = "string;some(thing) else + http://me@host:*/path-element.php";
    
    auto cs = ";()+/*-";
    using qi::char_;

    {
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), +~char_(cs) % +char_(cs), tokens);

        std::cout << "Condensing: ";
        for (auto& tok : tokens) {
            std::cout << " " << std::quoted(tok);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), *~char_(cs) % char_(cs), tokens);

        std::cout << "Not condensing: ";
        for (auto& tok : tokens) {
            std::cout << " " << std::quoted(tok);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Condensing:  "string" "some" "thing" " else " " http:" "me@host:" "path" "element.php"
Not condensing:  "string" "some" "thing" " else " " http:" "" "me@host:" "" "path" "element.php"
```

### X3

If you have c++14, you can use Spirit X3, which doesn't have the "auto problem" (because it doesn't have Proto Expression trees that can get dangling references).

Your original code [would have been fine in X3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2051be0cfd2c8956), and it will compile a lot faster.

Here's my example using X3:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ed1772035e59950)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
int main() {
    std::string const str = "string;some(thing) else + http://me@host:*/path-element.php";
    auto const cs = x3::char_(";()+/*-");

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    x3::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), +~cs % +cs, tokens);
    //x3::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), *~cs % cs, tokens);

    for (auto& tok : tokens) {
        std::cout << " " << std::quoted(tok);
    }
}
```

Printing

```
 "string" "some" "thing" " else " " http:" "me@host:" "path" "element.php"
```

Comment: Added a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0e93ff754a931de)

Comment: Also suggested [x3 with ditto demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ed1772035e59950)

Answer (score -3):

The thing is that using ( and closing it in double quotes is not really safe, it might get interpreted as something else entirely, you might want to try using / to escape it instead.

Comment: This is just inaccurate. This is C++, [string literals are well specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).