# Segmentation fault only in optimized builds in Boost.Spirit.Qi grammar initialization

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, boost

I ran into an odd issue writing a parser using Spirit Qi: I have a bug somewhere that is causing crashes with `-O` optimizations, but isn't with no optimizations. It crashes inside the constructor of the grammar:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct math_expression_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>
        expression,
        term,
        factorial,
        factor,
        pexpression,
        pfactor,
        nfactor,
        number;

    math_expression_grammar():
        math_expression_grammar::base_type(expression)
    {
        using namespace boost::spirit;
        using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;
        namespace sp = boost::spirit;
        namespace ph = boost::phoenix;

        auto sum = term[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('+') >> term[_val += sp::_1, _val += "+ "];
        auto difference = term[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('-') >> term[_val += sp::_1, _val += "- "];
        auto product = factor[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('*') >> factor[_val += sp::_1, _val += "* "];
        auto dividend = factor[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('/') >> factor[_val += sp::_1, _val += "/ "];

        expression = sum |
                     difference |
                     term;

        term = product |
               dividend |
               factor;

        pfactor = factorial.alias();
        nfactor = (lit('-') >> pfactor)[_val = sp::_1 + "n "];
        factor = nfactor | pfactor;

        pexpression = lit('(') >> expression >> lit(')');

        factorial = (pexpression | number)[_val = sp::_1] >> -lit('!')[_val += "! "];

        number = sp::double_[_val = ph::bind(stringize<double>, sp::_1) + ' '];
    }
};
```

I got to test it on TDM GCC 4.8.2 on Windows 64 bit, and GCC 4.9.0 on Arch Linux 64 bit; both had the same issue. Here's the relevant portion of the Valgrind trace, with optimizations turned on:

```
==15671== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==15671==    at 0x4040DA: void boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>, std::string (), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spiri
t::unused_type>::define<mpl_::bool_<false>, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_:
:tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag
ns_::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::subscript, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__norma
l_iterator<char*, std::string>, std::string (), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type>&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::
terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument
<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > > cons
t&>, 0l> >, 2l> const&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::fusion::vecto
r1<char> > >, 0l> const&>, 2l> const&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::subscript, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ch
ar*, std::string>, std::string (), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type>&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boo
st::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::sequence_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::plus_assign_eval, boo
st::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boo
st::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::plus_assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::phoen
ix::value<char const*>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusi
on::void_> >, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>
 > > const&>, 0l> >, 2l> const&>, 2l>&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::ta
g::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::subscript, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_itera
tor<char*, std::string>, std::string (), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type>&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::termina
l, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, bo
ost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > > const&>, 0l
> >, 2l> const&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::lit, boost::fusion::vector1<char
> > >, 0l> const&>, 2l> const&, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::subscript, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::spirit::
==15671==    by 0x404BD9: math_expression_grammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >::math_expression_grammar() (in /home/collin/programming/parser/parser)
==15671==    by 0x401E6A: main (in /home/collin/programming/parser/parser)
==15671==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==15671==    at 0x404672: math_expression_grammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >::math_expression_grammar() (in /home/collin/programming/parser/parser)
```

and here's the entire log with optimizations turned off:

```
==15686== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15686== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15686== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15686== Command: ./parser
==15686==

==15686==
==15686== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
==15686== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/5
==15686==    <inherited from parent>
==15686==
==15686== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/5
==15686==    <inherited from parent>
==15686==
==15686== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/5
==15686==    <inherited from parent>
==15686==
==15686==
==15686== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15686==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15686==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 14 frees, 776 bytes allocated
==15686==
==15686== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15686==
==15686== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15686== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

There was no change in any of my code between the two tests.

I'm having trouble actually debugging the issue since the bug strikes only with `-O` optimizations or higher, but not `-Og` unfortunately. I do have a suspicion the bug MAY be in Boost.Spirit, but I am also very unsure; I don't see anything wrong in my code, but I may be missing something or using Spirit wrong. Can someone more experienced point me in the right direction?

Here's the entire compile-able code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_real.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename NumType, typename Iterator>
NumType inline parse_number(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    using namespace std;

    istringstream extractor(string(first, last));
    NumType num;
    extractor >> num;

    return num;
}

template <typename NumType = double, typename Iterator>
NumType eval_rpn(Iterator head, Iterator last)
{
    using namespace std;

    const char tokens[] = {'+', '-', '*', '/', '^', 'n', ' '};
    auto tokens_begin = begin(tokens), tokens_end = end(tokens);

    stack<NumType> num_stack;

    while(head != last)
    {
        auto next = find_first_of(head, last, tokens_begin, tokens_end);

        if(head != next) num_stack.push(parse_number<NumType>(head, next));

        if(next != last)
        {
            NumType temp;

            switch(*next)
            {
            case '+':
                temp = num_stack.top();
                num_stack.pop();
                num_stack.top() += temp;
                break;

            case '-':
                temp = num_stack.top();
                num_stack.pop();
                num_stack.top() -= temp;
                break;

            case '*':
                temp = num_stack.top();
                num_stack.pop();
                num_stack.top() *= temp;
                break;

            case '/':
                temp = num_stack.top();
                num_stack.pop();
                num_stack.top() /= temp;
                break;

            case '^':
                temp = num_stack.top();
                num_stack.pop();
                num_stack.top() = pow(num_stack.top(), temp);
                break;

            case 'n':
                num_stack.top() = -num_stack.top();
                break;

            default:
                break; // Do nothing
            }

            head = next+1;
        }
        else head = last;
    }

    return num_stack.top();
}

template <typename T>
std::string stringize(T x)
{
    return std::to_string(x);
}

template <typename Iterator>
struct math_expression_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>
        expression,
        term,
        factorial,
        factor,
        pexpression,
        pfactor,
        nfactor,
        number;

    math_expression_grammar():
        math_expression_grammar::base_type(expression)
    {
        using namespace boost::spirit;
        using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;
        namespace sp = boost::spirit;
        namespace ph = boost::phoenix;

        auto sum = term[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('+') >> term[_val += sp::_1, _val += "+ "];
        auto difference = term[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('-') >> term[_val += sp::_1, _val += "- "];
        auto product = factor[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('*') >> factor[_val += sp::_1, _val += "* "];
        auto dividend = factor[_val = sp::_1] >> lit('/') >> factor[_val += sp::_1, _val += "/ "];

        expression = sum |
                     difference |
                     term;

        term = product |
               dividend |
               factor;

        pfactor = factorial.alias();
        nfactor = (lit('-') >> pfactor)[_val = sp::_1 + "n "];
        factor = nfactor | pfactor;

        pexpression = lit('(') >> expression >> lit(')');

        factorial = (pexpression | number)[_val = sp::_1] >> -lit('!')[_val += "! "];

        number = sp::double_[_val = ph::bind(stringize<double>, sp::_1) + ' '];
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    math_expression_grammar<string::iterator> g;

    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    while(input.size())
    {
        auto first = input.begin(), last = input.end();
        cout << input << endl;

        string result;
        if(!boost::spirit::qi::parse(first, last, g, result))
        {
            cout << "Error at " << last - first << ":\n\t" << *first << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << result << endl;
            cout << eval_rpn(result.begin(), result.end()) << endl;
        }

        getline(cin, input);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb It crashes upon starting the program (as that's when the math_expression_grammar class is constructed), there are no inputs. Unless you meant something else?

Comment: There's no `main()` in the code you posted. "testcase" means code that someone else can compile without making any changes, and reproduce your behaviour. That guarantees that we're both looking at the same thing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb OK, got it; I added it.

Comment: Is there any sample input/expected output? I can't tell what this is supposed to do. Why is there a semantic action every square inch? ("[Semantic actions are evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil/8259585#8259585)"). Why do all rules expose `std::string`? How would you handle whitespace?

Comment: @sehe it's a work in progress

Comment: @mebob that's okay, it just means I cannot fix it for you, but you already have the answer, so you can fix it yourself :) (there might be more details at play, but I would need to be able to do testruns and not knowing any valid input/output I can't see these.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot (safely) use `auto` on Spirit expression templates. That leads to UB.

<strike>Will post a fixed version soonish</strike>([awaiting information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318149/segmentation-fault-only-in-optimized-builds-in-boost-spirit-qi-grammar-initializ/24321511#comment37593442_24318149)). Meanwhile, see:

- [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)
- [boost spirit V2 qi bug associated with optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763665/boost-spirit-v2-qi-bug-associated-with-optimization-level/20766909#20766909)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it easily. The only reason why I have so many semantic actions right now is because I'm "debugging" the grammar